# Is there a Google Chrome extension that lets me define hotkeys for sites?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

This is driving me crazy because I tried all the Google searches I could think of and I still can't find a suitable addon.

I need an addon where I can define hotkeys that will take me to the sites of my choice (preferably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd>). They have to work without any conditions (meaning, you don't need to first activate "hotkey mode" or anything silly like that- they have to work as if they are native to Chrome), and they need to reload the current tab, not open a new one.

In other words, I'm looking for Firefox's Speed Dial hotkey experience. Anyone knows of an addon like that?

Comment: If the Firefox extension has any form of fan/dev community site (irc, email list, message board, etc.), you could check there to see if any of them (fans or developers) have considered porting it to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Sure do, they have one for everything!

Seems to be broken in Chrome 12 and up though, darn

Looks like development stopped in 2010.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omgmmhpgegfcifjmhpenmjpignkegpal

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this article](http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/use-hotkeys-to-launch-applications-without-any-software.html), you can specify various Ctrl-Shift- or Ctrl-Alt- hotkeys in Windows to launch applications. You just need to make some shortcuts for each website you want Google Chrome to open .. where the command line is something like

```
chrome http://www.yahoo.com
```

Then, go in the properties for the shortcut and specify the hotkey you wish. The hotkeys are processed on the Windows layer and so should work regardless of what other applications are active.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Chrome Keyconfig extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyconfig/okneonigbfnolfkmfgjmaeniipdjkgkl?hl=en).